# How persist one to one entity unidirectionally in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, relationship

I have a problem with two entities in Symfony2 with Doctrine:

This is the first Entity:

```
    /**
 * Pedidos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RestCarta\Bundle\FrontendBundle\Entity\PedidosRepository")
 */
class Pedidos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usuario", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $usuario;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mesa", type="string", length=3)
     */
    private $mesa;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Articulos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articulo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $articulo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="decimal")
     */
    private $precio;
```

This is the second Entity:

```
/**
 * Articulos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RestCarta\Bundle\FrontendBundle\Entity\ArticulosRepository")
 */
class Articulos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="referencia", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $referencia;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $descripcion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="decimal")
     */
    private $precio;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $imagen;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorias", inversedBy="articulos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoria_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $categoria;
```

And now the problem.

How i can persist one "Pedido" with contain one "Articulo" ??

I can read all "Pedido" and the LEFT JOIN with "Articulo" work perfectly, (data inserted manually via phpMyAdmin) but when I persist more data with this code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


$pedido = new Pedidos();
        $pedido->setUsuario('blablabla');
        $pedido->setMesa('blablabla'); 
        $pedido->setArticulo($identi);
        $pedido->setPrecio('blablabla');

        $em->persist($pedido);
        $em->flush();
```

$identi = corresponds to an id of "Articulos"

The result is:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RestCarta/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1388 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Please, anyone can help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: $identi must be a entity object, not only the ID  you can use `$em->getReference('YourNamespace\Articulos', $identi);`

Comment: Thx Rufinus!!! work perfect!!! please, answer question, not whit comment for approve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$identi` must be a entity object, not only the ID you can use

```
$em->getReference('YourNamespace\Articulos', $identi);
```